# Failure on fetching data from sqlsrv in php

Tags: php, azure, sqlsrv

I have such a statement:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$fetch = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT ID FROM login WHERE 
                         username='$user' AND password='$pass'");
$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($fetch);
```

However, `$count` value returns null. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Does it give an error?

Comment: Perhaps you should add a `die()` statement that tells you what the error is. We don't have enough to guess what it might be here.

Comment: It doesn't give an error Daan. Okay, I will put a die() operation to determine the error Jay Blanchard.

Comment: The following code is :                                                  print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    if($count!="")
    {
    session_register("sessionusername");
    $_SESSION['login_username']=$user;
    header("Location: /website/index.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
       header('Location:index.php');
    } But it doesn't go to /website/index.php it goes to index.php

Comment: Have a look at the sqlsrv_query() example on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php. It shows you how to output an error in case something is wrong...

Comment: and also it is the link: http://codepaste.net/kdrik8

Comment: And please use parameterized queries, as your sample is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: okay Reinder Wit, I will check now. thanks. :)

Comment: Jay Blanchard, and Reinder Wit, it gives such error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -50 [code] => -50 [2] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. [message] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might having an error in your database connection, or in your SQL statement. Check if $conn is set using print_r($conn), if is correctly setted, then you should check SQL statement  . Note that in PHP, SQL execution errors will not raise an exception, but a warning message, so this will not be catched in a try catch statement.

Comment: I will try now, thanks Tarciso Junior. :)

Comment: now I got such an error, Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -50 [code] => -50 [2] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. [message] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. ) )